# textbox and lable display

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and facing some small problem in it. Problem is to set the Display="Dynamic" for Textbox and label but it is showing some erroe and is there any equal tag like Display="Dynamic" for textbox and lable....,

**code is:**

```
<tr>
            <td align="right" style="padding-right: 5px; width: 50%;" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="FIRSTNAME :"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;" >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                    ErrorMessage="You can't leave this empty." Style="color: #FF0000;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

plz help me on this flow...,

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Please clarify.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, can we use the Display="Dynamic" tag in textbox feild if not what is the euqal tag for it...,

Comment: It's for validators only.

Comment: If you trying to show/hide the TextBox, use the Visible property. You can reach it both on the Page and the CodeBehind.